# calculating a textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, devextreme

I am working on a requirement where I want to do some calculation on the numbers entered in the dxtextbox,

For example if I am entering:

123456789

then the calculation will be like

```
num1=1 *3;num2=2 *7;num3=3 ;num4=4 *3;num5=5 *7;num6=6;num7=7 *3;num8=8*7;num9=9;
```

sum=num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8+num9

```
if(sum != 0 && sum % 10 == 0){it will return true}else it should return false
```

I searched this in your documentation section but didn't got any thing.

Can you please help me to solve this requirement .
I have attached a sample solution where you can see the kind of validation structure I trying to accomplish  this task.
Thank You

Comment: I do not see any meaning or specific order in your multiplication statement..

Comment: What are the rules for the calculation pattern? Always 9 digits? Please also show the code that you have tried

Comment: @RayonDabre took me a bit too but follows pattern of  multiply by 3,7,0 ..3,7,0 but doesn't make much sense beyond that

Comment: @charlietfl, Right! Looks something easier if OP provides more info..

Comment: amen to that ... serious lack of details here

Comment: would rather be 3, 7, 1 but makes not more sense at all :D
maybe crypting a hash?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var enteredNumber = 123456789;
    var numTotal = 0;
    var multiplikator = Array(3,7,1);
    var multiplikatorCnt = 0;
    for(a=0;a < enteredNumber.toString().length; a++)
    {
        numTotal += parseInt((enteredNumber.toString())[a]) * multiplikator[multiplikatorCnt];
        multiplikatorCnt++;
        if(multiplikatorCnt > 2)
        {
            multiplikatorCnt = 0;
        }
    }
    if(numTotal != 0 && numTotal % 10 == 0)
    {
        return true
    }
    else
    { 
        return false
    }
});
```

Edit: forgot to return true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter would be:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var enteredNumber = 123456789;
    var numTotal = 0;
    var multiplikator = Array(3,7,1);
    for(a=0;a < enteredNumber.toString().length; a++)
    {
        numTotal += parseInt((enteredNumber.toString())[a]) * multiplikator[a % multiplikator.length];
    }
    if(numTotal != 0 && numTotal % 10 == 0)
    {
        return true
    }
    else
    { 
        return false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for your quick response,I am able to solve it by my self

here is the code what I am using

```
var valuenum = $("#txt_value").dxTextBox("instance");
    var checknumber = valuenum .option('value');
    var arr = checknumber.split('');
    var num1, num2, num3, num4;

    num1 = (arr[0]) * 3;
    num2 = (arr[1]) * 7;
    num3 = (arr[2]);
    num4 = (arr[3]) * 3;


    var totalval = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2) + parseInt(num3) + parseInt(num4) ;
    if (totalval != 0 && totalval % 10 == 0) {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Ok. Great. Just one comment: Your solution isn't flexible. If you have a number with more than 4 digits, your solution will not work. Or do you have a limitation on your input field to 4 digits?